# Put a view on the edge of its parent view

Tags: android

I am trying to create layout on Android, to look the same as on the image. Problem is, I don't know how put only half of button inside parent view, and another one outside. I need something to align center of button to the edge of parent. I know, it's possible with java code, but I want to avoid it. Any sugestions? Sorry for my english. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to put the button into that view as a child, but over the view in a higher Z order with a different bottom margin.

You can start from this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="30dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="40dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]